# Unable to install cider to emacs - package not found

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04
Added openjdk-11 and lein 2.9.3

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
```

Installed
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14)
 of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian

Tried [the instructions](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/installation.html) on the cider Getting Started page

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
M-x package install <RET>
cider <RET>
```

The cider package isn't found. Tried to package-list-packages - list doesn't contain cider.
What am I missing?

Finally did the steps from the following link to get it to work 
[Brave Clojure book companion repo](https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure)

Comment: what is the value of `package-archives`? does it contain melpa?

Comment: @Rorschach - your question sent me on a quest on how to print that variable >> M-: >> M-x ielm and finally to solve the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure why the cider instructions don't mention this.

You need to create a ~/.emacs.d/init.el file with the following contents

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

Save and restart emacs.

`M-x package-list-packages` check the archive column shows packages from **gnu** as well as **melpa** archives.

- Sometimes you would see an error *Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.* - this one is a flaky one. A restart and/or `M-x package-refresh-contents` fixed it for me.

Now we have the sources configured correctly.

1. Install:
   `M-x package-install <RET> cider <RET>`
2. `M-x package-list-packages` - Move to the end of the listing to see Status=installed packages.
3. Test: `M-x cider-jack-in`. Answer no to the prompt indicating you are not in a clojure project. Soon you should be dropped to a `user>` prompt - ready to REPL and roll.

Comment: It didn't work for me until I deleted init.el and added it in .emacs ...

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider trying out popular existing "bundle setups' like [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) and [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) Both of which have all the tooling necessary for Clojure development built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying .emacs or init file manually, you can just change the package-archives variable by typing the following:

```
M-x customize-variable package-archives
```

By default, you should only have a GNU source set. Go ahead and add Melpa's name and URL (https://melpa.org/packages/) too by clicking INS. Then apply the changes. Next, type the following commands into the terminal:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents  [RET]
M-x package-install [RET] cider [RET]
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

CIDER is available on the two major package.el community maintained repos - MELPA Stable and MELPA.

After adding the following in my ./emacs, i could install CIDER.

```
(setq package-archives
    '(("Elpa"     . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
      ("Melpa Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
      ("Melpa"        . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
      ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
    package-archive-priorities
    '(("MELPA Stable" . 10)
      ("GNU ELPA"     . 5)
      ("MELPA"        . 0)))
```